# Java: difference and use between ThreadPool and ThreadGroup?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a bots creator in java and I was using for along time individual Threads; for me its very important build applications with multithreading. Yesterday I was reading a little about Thread Pool and Thread Group, but I don't really know which is better to use. So I wanna read opinions most colloquial about these issues, example uses, efficiency, easy implementation etc...

Any opinion is important for me, thanks to everyone that reply to me.

```
I use this online to open the post. I dont have any code.
```

Comment: A _pool_ of any type is a collection of objects that can be re-used.  Some objects, like `Threads`, are expensive to create.  An application that re-uses them performs better than one that continually creates and destroys objects.  Threads in a thread pool all have the same `run()` method:  It loops, trying to `take()` a _task_ (e.g., a `Runnable`) from a queue, and each time it gets one, it _performs_ the task (calls `task.run()`), and then, it goes back to waiting for another one.  See the javadoc for java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor for more information.

Answer (score 15):

Thread group class was created in JDK 1.0 to manage the state of multiple threads at once e.g suspend, resume etc. Later most of its important methods were deprecated because of potential deadlock they can create.

Thread pool is an architectural concept where multiple threads form a worker pool that works together. Instead of spanning one thread per task, the pool of threads are created at the start and they pick tasks from queue-like data structure one by one and execute them. Once a task is executed each task is ready to serve another task in the queue. Executor framework in Java 1.5 uses a thread pool in this context.

Comment: Good answer, Puja. But please don't add unrelated links or a signature to your posts. You can link to personal or business websites, or anything you want to promote, from your profile page.